# Install mongo-connector on windows

Tags: python, mongodb

I installed python, pymongo via easy_install script and tired the command easy_install mongo-connector. But after installation I could not find mongo_connector.py in the python directory? Was there some issue by installing mongo-connector?

Then I tired python setup.py install for the downloaded mongodb-connector.tar.gz and it installed the package.

```
PS C:\Python33> python C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\mongo-connector\mongo_connector.py -m localhost:27017 -t http://loc
alhost:8080/solr
2014-01-23 16:52:55,596 - INFO - Beginning Mongo Connector
2014-01-23 16:52:55,596 - INFO - No doc manager specified, using simulator.
2014-01-23 16:52:56,596 - CRITICAL - MongoC`onnector: Can't find OplogProgress file!
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 901, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\mongo-connector\mongo_connector.py", line 204, in run
    repl_set = prim_admin.command("replSetGetStatus")['set']
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo-2.6.3-py3.3-win-amd64.egg\pymongo\database.py", line 396, in command
    msg, allowable_errors)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo-2.6.3-py3.3-win-amd64.egg\pymongo\helpers.py", line 147, in _check_command
_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('replSetGetStatus', 1)]) failed: not running with --replSet
```

But the connector wont work, has anybody experience by using mongo-connector on windows?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be running a replica set instead of a standalone mongod to get mongo-connector to work, as described in the readme: https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector/blob/master/README.markdown

The reason for this is that mongo connector relies on the systems in place that allow replica sets to copy each other (the `Oplog` mentioned in the error) in order to copy your data. If you are just trying this out on a single machine, it's still possible to configure a replica set by starting multiple processes on the same machine. See the docs here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

Comment: Hi, I followed the introductions [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) and now I get the error `2014-01-24 09:51:34,824 - CRITICAL - MongoConnector: Bad target system URL!
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 901, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\mongo-connector\mongo_connector.py", line 210, in run
    False, self.doc_manager,
AttributeError: 'Connector' object has no attribute 'doc_manager'`

Comment: Hm, not totally sure about that one. Maybe this is helpful: https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector/issues/23 ?

Comment: Thx this helped me to think about the target URL. I was using a wrong port. But now I get an other Error: `Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 901, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\mongo-connector\oplog_manager.py", line 101, in run
    cursor = self.init_cursor()
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\mongo-connector\oplog_manager.py", line 298, in init_cursor
    timestamp = self.dump_collection()...`

Comment: you might want to open a new SO question for that one. I'm not sure whats going wrong just looking at it